# Magento MAGMI import CSV: what does attribute_set column mean/require

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magmi

In MAGMI, what does the required attribute_set column need to have in it? I can seem to find out anywhere. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try a name of an attribute set as defined under `Catalog -> Attributes -> Mange Attribute Sets`.

Enter `Default` if you did not specify any special attribute sets.